# error Unknown column 'Extent1.id' in 'where clause' within where of list in mysql & EF6

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I use Mysql WorkBench and Entity framework 6. I want to add the condition "where" for previously query. if I add condition for **simple attribute** (`string`), it successfully. But I add condition for `List<object>`, it is the error message "**Unknown column 'Extent1.id' in 'where clause'**.

How can i add condition for query, with condition is list

Query select:

```
var result = from mus in ct.musics
     where  mus.state == Contant.Keys.StateAction.A.ToString()
     select (new
     {
           MusicKey = mus.id,
           OptionKey = mus.musicoptions.Select(i => i.OptionsId),
     });
```

after i add another **Where(List)** for **result**. *it is error Unknown column 'Extent1.id' in 'where clause*

```
 foreach (ClassOption obj in request.Options)
       {
            if (obj.type.ToString() == "opt")
             {

               string a = obj.key.ToString();
               result = result.Where(i => i.OptionKey.ToList().Contains(a));
             }
        }
```

but i add another **Where(simple)** for **result**. *it is success*

```
foreach (ClassOption obj in request.Options)
           {
                if (obj.type.ToString() == "opt")
                 {

                   string a = obj.key.ToString();
                   result = result.Where(i => i.MusicKey == "test");
                 }
            }
```

*note*: before I used ms sql 2008 and EF6 the previous statement can run, but when I  changed to use mysql, it was an error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your condition should be something like this:

```
result = result.Where(i => i.OptionKey.ToString().ToList().Contains(a));
```

Comment: I don't think it is i.OptionKey.ToString().ToList(). Because i.OptionKey is List<String>.

Comment: Well, you have `.Select(i => i.OptionsId)` in the code above. Is `OptionsId` `int` or `string`?